# Cocoapods - Add sources in a settings file to stop typing --sources for private sources

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have a private pod that uses resources from a private repo.

Every time I have to create a new version when I need to push the new version, I need to add the private sources and the cocoaPod one:

```
pod repo push myRepo myPod.podspec --allow-warnings --sources=git@github.com:myCompany/myPodRepo.git,git@github.com:CocoaPods/Specs.git
```

Is there any way to make this more "automatic" ?

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont need to use --sources. Before push, you have to add it. This is what I use every time I want to make an  update:

```
pod repo add YourFramework YourGITUrl
pod repo push YourFramework YourFramework.podspec --allow-warnings
```